# Check my integral please -- conversion to spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to solve

$$E=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2+m^2}$$

This is totally trivial, I think.  Convert to spherical polar with

$$ dx~dy~dz = r^2\sin\theta ~dr~d\theta~d\Phi\quad\text{and}\quad r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$

so that

$$E=-\int_{0}^{\infty}dr\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\Phi\dfrac{r^2\sin\theta}{r^2+m^2}$$

$$E=-4\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}dr\dfrac{r^2}{r^2+m^2}$$

What is the way to integrate this final integral?

Comment: You should have $-4\pi$ at your last step as your constant in front of the integral.

Comment: Oh, yeah oops!  I messed up the minus sign there.

Comment: *Hint:* Does the last integral converge? Try writing:
$$r^2=(r^2+m^2)-m^2$$

Comment: As an alternative to what has already been suggested by projectilemotion, notice that $$\lim_{r\to +\infty}\frac{r^2}{r^2+m^2}=1\neq 0.$$ Thus, what can you conclude about the last integral?

Answer (score 1):

For any $\rho>0$, the surface area of $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$ is $4\pi\rho^2$, hence
$$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{x^2+y^2+z^2+m^2} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4\pi\rho^2}{\rho^2+m^2}\,d\rho $$
is not convergent since $\frac{\rho^2}{\rho^2+m^2}\to 1\neq 0$ as $\rho\to+\infty$.

**Note**: I am not saying that a positive, integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ has to converge to zero as long as its parameter goes to $+\infty$ - this is not true. I am exploiting the fact that *if* a positive, integrable function converges to something, this *something* has to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend2m%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend1i%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1i%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart3%22%7D+-%3E%22-infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart2m%22%7D+-%3E%22-infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22volume+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22-1%2F%5Bx%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2%2Bm%5E2%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart1i%22%7D+-%3E%22-infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2m%22%7D+-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable3%22%7D+-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend3%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22
The integral is non-convergent.